# fork/exec /bin/sh invalid argument

Tags: go, exec, system-calls, invalid-argument

The issue is not stably reproduced on mac. the code snippet is as below:

```
cmd := exec.Command("/bin/zsh", "-c", `brew info goland`)
cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
    Credential: &syscall.Credential{
        Uid:    501,
        Gid:    20,
        Groups: []uint32{2, 3, 4},
    },
}
output, err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
if err != nil {
    println(err)
}
```

i run the process as root, and exec command with another user. It failed on some mac computer and report "fork/exec /bin/zsh invalid argument" error message.
anybody know the cause? thanks~

Comment: What is different between the computers? Are the UID/GID/Groups values all valid on all systems, with all the same permissions? Is the Go version the same? Is the OS version the same?

Comment: Does the user have permission to run /bin/zsh? Does the computer have enough resources to create a new process? This probably doesn't have anything to do with Go itself but OS level fork/exec returning EINVAL.

Comment: @JimB The UID/GID is different, they are generated by the user of the systems, and the OS version also different.

Comment: @blami they have permission to run /bin/zsh, they can manually run the command in the shell

Comment: I have found the root cause which is the NGROUP_MAX is 16 in mac, here the number of groups the user belongs to is more than 16.

Comment: You should promote your comment to an answer @GordonLiu I had exactly this same problem and your comment found the solution for me. Thanks!